# The android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout is not declared

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm creating new android application using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015.
I added the component Android Support Design Library 23.4.0.1 to my Projects (Components) 
In my layout (Main.axml) I copy and past from the Getting Started https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamandroidsupportdesign 
But I get error The android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout is not declared

Any ideas?

Maxin.axml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Where do you get this error? Maybe it is just a warning because the xmlns does not contain a definition for it?

Answer (score 3):

Try uninstalling the Support Libraries and then reinstalling them again.

If that doesn't work, try going into `C:\Users\{Your User}\AppData\Local\Xamarin` and delete all folders in there. Then do a Clean and Rebuild in Visual Studio.