# How to translate Java import to C# using statement

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm building an Android app in `Xamarin.Android`. In Java terms, I need to `import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;`. How can I do this with a C# `using` statement?

Xamarin intellisense won't let me go past `using Android.Support`. When I add `.Design` it tells me the using directive is unnecessary, and throws build errors.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Could you show your C# code?

Comment: Do you have all of the packages and components you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing a component. Try including the Android Design Support Library component, I think it'll fix your problem.

If that doesn't work, try the steps listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018779/the-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout-is-not-declared).

Comment: Yes, it looks like that was the issue. I'm running into more problems now trying to use `CoordinatorLayout`, but adding that component fixed my initial roadblock. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Double click on your packages folder inside your Xamarin Android project. The NuGet package search window will appear. In the search field (top right corner) type "Xamarin.Android.support.design". Select the package from Xamarin Inc.

Also helpful might be Xamarin.Android.Support.Contraint.Layout and Xamarin.Android.Support.Contraint.Layout.Solver. These are pre-release packages so you need to check the "Show pre-release packages" checkbox.

Comment: I'm not seeing either of those 2 other packages in the Xamarin Add Packages window, even with "Show pre-release packages" checkbox checked. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea. I checked it while I was writing my answer.

Comment: Ok, no worries. I've got the issue resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use using Android.Support.Design.Widget; and make sure you're using the Xamarin.Android.Support.Design package from NuGet.