# CoordinatorLayout element isn't declared

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin, android-support-library

I'm a bit new to programming so bear with me. I'm trying to create a FAB menu by following ResoCoder's tutorial on youtube, but there's an issue with the CoordinatorLayout element being declared.

It throws this warning:

> The 'android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout' is not declared.

Here's the AXML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello FAB menu!"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>

  <View
    android:id="@+id/bg_fab_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#48000000"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_airballoon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard_23"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:rotation="90"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_airballoon"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is an image of the warning.

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlKxY.png)

edit:

This is now showing on the 'Designer' tab

[Error on designer tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5dG2.png)

Comment: possibly duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39059910

Comment: Nope ;^( Read my comment on your answer.

Comment: 1. So recently I encountered this error while building my application, What I was doing the XML in which I had CoordinatorLayout creating it inside the drawable folder, which is wrong. So put that in layout folder and it will resolve your problem.

2. Add:     implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
inside build.gradle app.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer :

It's just a warning and not an error, you could compile your project without any problem.

#### Long Answer :

The problem is that the Intellisense could not pick the attributes you type although those attributes did exists in android SDK. So the Visual Studio shows that :

```
The 'android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout' is not declared.
```

To solve this problem, you should [enable Intellisense in Android .axml files](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/questions/enable-axml-intellisense/). But a little difference with the document, you could download `android-layout-xml.xsd` and `schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd` file from the following link :

- https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/android-layout-xml.xsd
- https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd

Download the file and  edit the `android-layout-xml.xsd` and add the  `ConstraintLayout` element. Then move these file manually to :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\XML\Schemas\1033
```

Or simply just add these schemas within Visual Studio. Restart your VS, this warning will be gone

#### Suggestion :

It is recommend that ignoring the warning, you could compile your project  without any problem.

## Update :

> Otherwise, after compiling I get errors like: 'Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_margin' with value '@dimen/standard_23').' Which I assume are because of the CoordinatorLayout not being declared.

The `dimen` attribute need you create on yourself, make sure you copied the `dimens.xml` file too. You need create the `dimens.xml` in `Resource\values\dimens.xml`, define the `standard_23` size in this file. Then the compile could find the `standard_23` size.

**dimen.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <dimen name="action_button_min_width">56dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="indeterminate_progress_size">32dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="standard_23">23dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

Comment: It isn't compiling correctly anyways. I did what you said, but it didn't help either.

Comment: @Alasdair, yeah, it's a little complex to remove the warning, just ignore the warning will be fine.

Comment: @Alasdair, when your project compile failed,  what is the error ? Please post the error message. And please make sure you have install the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` nuget package.

Comment: I made sure the nuget package was installed. I'll post the error later tonight when I have time. thanks.

Comment: There was an error that appeared on the designer tab before compiling, so I edited the main post and put it on there. Otherwise, after compiling I get errors like: 'Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_margin' with value '@dimen/standard_23').' Which I assume are because of the CoordinatorLayout not being declared.

Comment: @Alasdair, clean your solution, delete the bin and obj file, restart your visual studio, it should be work.

Comment: @Alasdair, sorry for late, I have update my answer, you could check it.

Comment: It seems like the CoordinatorLayout warning has been fixed, and I managed to work out all the other errors myself. Thanks! But it seems that the screen that was on the designer tab is still there, and the UI isn't loading. Any other ideas for that?

Comment: @Alasdair, you could deploy the project but on the designer tab is still has error ?